# Microsoft Edge 84 released but WebView2 is not working as promised

Tags: microsoft-edge, webview2

I was waiting for Microsoft Edge 84 to be released so that WebView2 is included as they promise.. but after updating Edge, WebView2 is not working...

For example CoreWebView2Ready never fired and WebView2 is showing nothing and it is throwing exception on resize!

WebView2 is working fine only when installing Canary channel version on target machine.

Comment: What version of WebView2 have you installed?

Comment: 0.9.515-prerelease

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used 0.9.515-prerelease and as stated in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/releasenotes#09515-prerelease it requires Microsoft Edge 84 or higher.

In real it requires Evergreen WebView2 Runtime Installer to be distributed to work on the target machine.

The other way to make it work without WebView2 Runtime Installer is to install Canary channel on target machine which is now on version 86.